# How can I call the cancellation of a running method from another method. c# .core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

```
[HttpPost("WorkHard ")]
public ActionResult WorkHard ()
{
   ///
}

[HttpGet("CancelWorkHard ")]
public void CancelWorkHard ()
{

}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads

Comment: Multtiasking in ASP.Net is usually done on the client side. For the server side, the page is to be (re)created, processed, send to the user and dropped from memory ASAP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140) So either you would keep the page in memory or never get to see the finish. | Multitasking is usually done via AJAX or a similar thing on the client side. Sometimes even calling a different server. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38501/Multi-Threading-in-ASP-NET-2

Answer (score 0):

Even though I wouldn't recomend to do so, here's the code that might give you an idea:

```
    private static CancellationTokenSource TokenSource { get; set; }
    private static Int32 Counter { get; set; }

    [HttpPost("WorkHard")]
    public IActionResult WorkHard()
    {
        TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
          {
              while (true)
              {
                  TokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                  await Task.Delay(500);
                  Counter++;
              }
          }, TokenSource.Token);

        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost("CancelWorkHard")]
    public IActionResult CancelWorkHard()
    {
        TokenSource.Cancel();
        return Ok(Counter);
    }
```